# Saving data to SD card and updating them

Tags: android, serialization, android-sdcard

I can't figure out how get this code to work. My first problem is I am not sure if my condition `file.exist()` works how it should. This code should look on an SD card to see if there is a file then save my serialized object and add new data and then save it again. If the file isn't on the SD card then it should create it. The only thing I get from the log is:

```
09-09 18:48:45.241  15415-15415/com.dami.CourierServiceee V/LOGSD: read from SD
09-09 18:48:45.361  15415-15415/com.dami.CourierServiceee V/LOGSD: fread from SD works?
09-09 18:48:45.361  15415-15415/com.dami.CourierServiceee V/LOGSD: repeated wrote -------
```

Here is my code

```
   private void SaveDataToSDCard(List<PictureObject> listsave) {

    String filename = "pictures.data";
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File dir = new File(root + "/courier/saved/");
    File file = new File(dir,filename);

    if (file.exists()){
        // restore data from SD card and add new data to list and then save them to SD card
        try {
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                Log.v("FileIOService", "No Such Directory Exists");
            }

            ListOflists = new ArrayList<List<PictureObject>>();
            Log.v("LOGSD", "read from SD");
            ListOflists = RestoreDataFromSDCard(file,dir);
            Log.v("LOGSD", "read from SD works?");

            ListOflists.add(listsave);
            SerializePictureObject serialize1 = new SerializePictureObject(ListOflists);

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

            Log.v("LOGSD", "repeated wrote -------");
            oos.writeObject(serialize1);
            oos.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }else{
        // write data to SD card
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = null;

        try {
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                dir.mkdirs();
            }

            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);

            Log.v("LOGSD", "  saving to SD ------------");
            ListOflists = new ArrayList<List<PictureObject>>();
            ListOflists.add(listsave);
            SerializePictureObject serialize = new SerializePictureObject(ListOflists);

            objectOutputStream.writeObject(serialize);
            objectOutputStream.close();
            Log.v("LOGSD", " saving o SD");

        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            ioException.getMessage();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }
}

public static List<List<PictureObject>> RestoreDataFromSDCard(File file,File dir){

    FileInputStream fistream = null;
    ObjectInputStream oistream = null;

    List<List<PictureObject>> pomlist = new ArrayList<List<PictureObject>>();
    SerializePictureObject pom;

    try {
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            Log.v("FileIOService", "No Such Directory Exists restoredatafromsdcard");
        }
        fistream = new FileInputStream(file);
        oistream = new ObjectInputStream(fistream);
         pom = (SerializePictureObject) oistream.readObject();
        Log.v("LOGSD", " behem nacitani z SD karty");
         pomlist = pom.get_serializeList();
        oistream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return pomlist;
}
```

I will be rly happy for any kind of help guys :)

```
java.io.WriteAbortedException: Read an exception; java.io.NotSerializableException: com.dami.CourierServiceee.FinishHandOver$PictureObject
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.dami.CourierServiceee.FinishHandOver$PictureObject
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.dami.CourierServiceee.FinishHandOver$PictureObject
```

Here is serializepictureobject hold lists of PictureObjecs and PictureObjecs hold Bitmap, string, string, string

```
    public class SerializePictureObject implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 123456789;
    List<List<PictureObject>> _serializeList = null;

    public SerializePictureObject(List<List<PictureObject>> _serializeList) {
        this._serializeList = _serializeList;
    }

    public List<List<PictureObject>> get_serializeList() {
        return _serializeList;
    }

    public void set_serializeList(List<List<PictureObject>> _serializeList) {
        this._serializeList = _serializeList;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Maybe is problem is this:

```
09-10 11:19:13.671      620-620/com.dami.CourierServiceee W/System.err: java.io.WriteAbortedException: Read an exception; java.io.NotSerializableException: android.graphics.Bitmap
09-10 11:19:13.701      620-620/com.dami.CourierServiceee W/System.err: Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: android.graphics.Bitmap
09-10 11:19:13.821      620-620/com.dami.CourierServiceee W/System.err: java.io.NotSerializableException: android.graphics.Bitmap
```

Comment: Have you included permission in your manifest to modify sdcard content?

Comment: my manifest looks like this:    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

Comment: Your manifest seems to be Okay!
Try catching FileNotFoundExcpetion and IOException both, instead of Exception.!.!

Comment: Same result after adding this catches

Comment: Exceptions added above !

Comment: can you post your class SerializePictureObject?

Comment: SerializePictureObject is added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe add this

```
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

Comment: put that before the oos.close();

Comment: oos.writeObject(serialize1);
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
                oos.close();  but same problem apear..

Comment: 620-620/com.dami.CourierServiceee W/System.err: java.io.WriteAbortedException: Read an exception; java.io.NotSerializableException: android.graphics.Bitmap